# How did traders calculate that the expected number of rate hikes is 4 based on eurodollar futures on 15Feb2018?

Tags: interest-rates, futures, eurodollars

https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-02-14/bond-traders-swarm-2019-fed-hike-bets-after-inflation-surprise

> After a Wednesday report showed consumer prices rose in January by
>   more than projected, traders used eurodollar futures to express their
>   view that central bankers have a clearer path to tighten. The expected
>   number of increases from now until the end of next year is up to four,
>   from 3.6 before the inflation report.

Comment: As @lliane has pointed out, this is not a good way to calculate expected rate hikes, since Eurodollar futures 1) trade at a time-varying spread to Fed funds, and 2) cover a 3-month window which can easily span two FOMC meetings. Instead, you should consult Fed Funds futures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yield of Dec19 Future - Current 3Months Libor / 25 bps (1 rate hike)

Libor 3M = 1.84 %
Price of Dec 19 Future (Ticker EDZ9) = 97.18 = 2.82 %

Number of hikes = (2.82 - 1.84)/0.25 = 4

Please note these are very simplifying assumptions, as the 3 months Libor is just a proxy on the Fed Funds Target rate.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience Chinese whispers between IR traders and bank/institution strategy/researchers and then journalists is rife. Hikes/cuts are predicted by traders based on FedFund futures or meeting period FFOIS rates. The same goes for GBP or EUR where the OIS rates dictate the probability of hikes/cuts.

Note that your quote didn't directly say the expected number of increases was calculated from the eurodollar futures. It said they were used to express a view. Which is sensible because they are a very liquid product with minimal execution cost. But they are a proxy to bank rate as Lilane states.

As an aside if you assume that the LIBOR/OIS basis is stable over a short period of time and the Eurodollar strip moved 10bps, you can assume the OIS strip moves 10bps also which accounts for 10/25= 40% of a 25bp hike.